# use variable in excel formula

Tags: vba, excel, variables, formula

I'm trying to make an automated sum based on an increasing number of rows.

Here is my sample of code but I'm stuck as I don't know the syntax to include a variable in the formula of a cell.

```
Sheets("Orderboek").Select

Range("H" & (rOi + 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=Sum(H3:H"&rOi&")"
```

My variables are declared as follows:

```
Dim i As Integer, a As Range    'i= index a een gebied
Dim prText As String    'product text
Dim rOi As Long         'rij nummer in orderboek
Dim rng, sumrng As Excel.Range
Dim r As Long           'rij number in offerte
Dim Tot As Long         'totaal som van offerte
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
```

Thanks very much if you can help me out.

Comment: This sounds silly, I know, but try adding some space: `Range("H"&(rOi + 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=Sum(H3:H" & rOi & ")"`. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Range("H" & (rOi + 1)).Formula = "=Sum(H3:H" & rOi & ")"
```

Make sure you use `.Formula` and not `.FormulaR1C1` in this case. Also make sure that there are spaces between ampersands.

Comment: Thanks, it was something this simple I thought later last night.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `FormulaR1C1` is useful when you want to refer to a certain point and would like to enter row and cell coordinates. Since you know the column you want to work with, using `Formula` is better. **i'll delete soon; just can't comment yet (<50rep)**

*edit: so @timthebomb is spot-on. :)