# Excel Formula can't see variable in it

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2003, vba

**What I have:**
1.) Dictionary

```
Set DictN= CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
arr = Sheet3.Range("D27", "H107").Value
For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    DictN.Item(arr (i, 1)) = CStr(arr (i, 5))
Next
```

2.) Public Function in ThisWorkbook that returns value from dictionary.

```
Public Function DictV(Dict As Object, Key As String)
    If InStr(1, Key, " flash") > 0 Then Key= Left(Key, InStr(1, Key, " flash") - 1)
    DictV = Dict(Key)
End Function
```

3.) Realy bad code, part of which doesnt seem to work

```
With Sheet2
        .Range("AD2:AD" & NumR).FormulaR1C1 = "=Test.xls!DictV(" & DictN & ",RC14)"
        .Range("AD2:AD" & NumR) = .Range("AD2:AD" & NumR).Value
End With
```

**What I get:**
1.) Formula returns incorrect values, my guess it is because it cannot see variables in my udf.
Any suggestions how to correct it?
[use variable in excel formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661730/use-variable-in-excel-formula) this didnt help me either.
**Upd:**
Now I get Run-time error '405', as it could not get any worse

Comment: Excel 2003. Really? This is 2017. Excel 2003 key design decisions were made in 2000, three years before it was released. How many years do you expect things to work with outdated software on updated operating systems? BTW, what OS are you using?

Comment: Excel formulas cannot see variables within VBA.  (And I can't see how you are getting `..  & DictN & ..` to work - VBA shouldn't be able to convert an entire `Dictionary` to a `String`.)

Comment: @teylyn Windows 7 x64 SP1, no matter how outdated it might be, it gets things done to me, the problem is in syntax which I didnt figure out yet.  @YowE3K I'm not trying to convert `Dictionary` to a `String`, even more, I used variables in formulas as in `ws1.Range("B10:J" & NumR2).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ws2!RC16=LOOKUP(ws2!RC16,ws3!R2C30:R" & NumR1 & "C30),""1"",""0"")`  I don't understand why can't i use it as variable for udf

Comment: Which formula returns the incorrect value? What is "Upd"?

Comment: @Variatus formula 3.)..., Upd=Update, I ran it again and got run-time error

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot have variable from your code visible in a formula in the sheet. Instead of using vba for this, can you not just use **`VLookUp`**?

Comment: @Zac Sheet3, where I get values for my `Dictionary` is in another Workbook, everytime I refer to data in another Workbook in my formula i get unpleasant error and it doesnt compute at all.

Comment: :) you are still think of the solution to this problem to be resolved by vba code. What I'm suggesting is that if you use `VLookUp` as a formula in your cells (which can lookup values from another sheet). Or maybe I don't completely understand the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with `Option Explicit` and the `Dim` statement. The latter assigns an address in the RAM, basically a "house" number, and associates it with a name. A name is easier for you to recognise, but VBA will translate the name you give into a number because that is how it finds things in the RAM. The `Dim` statement is used to "declare" a variable.

If you omit declarations, VBA will create variables as you name them, always as Variants. The `Option Explicit` option suppresses automatic declaring which is a good thing and will save you from becoming bold prematurely.

By the method you use to declare a variable you determine its "scope" or its "visibility". Anything declared inside a procedure is visible only within that procedure. Declarations on module level, not inside any procedure, are visible throughput the module where they are declared, and if they are declared as `Public` they will be visible anywhere in the project. Here are some examples.

```
Sub CreateDict()

    Dim DictN As Object
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set DictN = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Arr = Sheet3.Range("D27", "H107").Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(Arr)
        DictN.Item(Arr(i, 1)) = CStr(Arr(i, 5))
    Next
End Sub
```

As you can see, the variable `DictN` is declared within the sub. It is visible only to the code in that sub, nowhere else. In the next example, the variable of that same name is declared outside the procedure (preferably at the top of the module).

```
    Dim DictN As Object

Sub SetDict()

    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set DictN = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Arr = Sheet3.Range("D27", "H107").Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(Arr)
        DictN.Item(Arr(i, 1)) = CStr(Arr(i, 5))
    Next
End Sub
```

Observe that the variable isn't declared in the sub. It already exists because it was declared at the top of the module, and the sub just uses it. DictN is available throughout the module where it was declared, but not in other modules. The values assigned to it by the procedure `SetDict` stay in the dictionary (object) even after the sub has run. In fact, the sub is used to load it.

In the next example, the dictionary is returned from a function.

```
Private Function Dict() As Object

    Dim Fun As Object                   ' Function return value
    Dim Arr() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set Fun = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Arr = Sheet3.Range("D27", "H107").Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(Arr)
        Fun.Item(Arr(i, 1)) = CStr(Arr(i, 5))
    Next

    Set Dict = Fun
End Function
```

The function is `Private`, meaning it is visible within the module where it resides. If you want to call it from other modules you must declare it as `Public`. Actually VBA's default is `Public`. So, if you omit the word `Private` it will be public by default.

You can write code like `MyString = DictN(Key)` anywhere on the module provided the module level variable `DictN` exists. You can also write code like `MyString = Dict(Key)`, also anywhere on the module where the function `Dict` exists. The difference is that the function will create the dictionary on each call while the variable `DictN` was most likely loaded once and is then being reused.

Note, if you have examples 1 and 2 in the same module the code will fail to compile because the object DictN is declared both at procedure level and at module level. You can use a name only once. (Bear in mind that some names are used by VBA itself.)

Your code (given to us without declarations) seems to have the structure of my example #1. `DictN` is declared at procedure level and therefore not available in another procedure. Except, of course, you may not have declared it at all, trusting VBA to do the job for you. It did. You created the name at procedure level when you first used it and a procedure level variable was created. It isn't VBA's fault that you expect it to be available elsewhere too. :-)

Comment: I will accept this one for all your hard work and time wasted on me to explain but it doesn't apply to my problem unless I miss something. I'll show full code once I get back to workplace, I assure you I declared everything within one Sub (because I only have one, except for subsidiary Subs for opening files and turning off excel built-in functions).

Comment: Thank you. I'll gladly look at your code once you publish it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say where correction of your code might start, but easy to agree that the part you designated as bad was correctly diagnosed. Here is a slightly better version of it.

```
Dim WsSource As Worksheet
Dim Cell As Range

Set WsSource = Workbooks("Test.xls").Sheets(DictV(DictN, Key))
For Each Cell In Sheet2.Range("AD2", "AD" & NMR)
    Cell.Value = ws.Cells([Row], [Column]).Value
Next Cell
```

Don't hold your breath. It doesn't work, but it's better at showing its shortcomings than its original.

First, I suggest not to create a worksheet formula to get the data and then convert the formula to data. The data can be written directly into the cells.

So, I have created the object `WsSource`. I hope I understood your intention correctly: the sheet name is to be extracted from the dictionary. You should test `DictV(DictN, Key)` by itself and get it to work, because this is the bad apple in the basket. The Function DictV requires the dictionary DictN as well as a key.

1. DictN could be a function, called by DictV or it could be a public variable. It can't be a variable limited in scope to some undefined part of the code (sub or function) somewhere. You have to make it available. I point out that, if it is a function it can be called by DictV, and if it's a public variable it's available to DictV. Therefore why the parameter?
2. You seem to have identified the Key as "RC14". I'm not familiar with the RC notations and don't want to learn now. You might specify the cell as an offset from `Cell`.

Thus far you have specified the workbook and the worksheet from where you want to import a value. The cell, row and column, are undefined. Your code seems to give no hint as to your intention.

I have tried to make the code more transparent and hope that will help you fill in the omissions and make it work.

Comment: I should have described it more correctly. **DictV** is a `Public Function` that simply draws value from a `Dictionary` (it works for any `Dictionary` and Key I put as variables) by key which is RC14 (column "N" in the sheet where I use formula, it works great for this formula). I fill the dictionary with data from another `Workbook`, which is why I cannot use **`VLOOKUP`** instead (I get an error that states that I use too many data sources). **DictN** is this particular `Dictionary`. Its neither a function nor Public variable. My english is bad and I can't express my thoughts correctly.

Comment: `Sheet2.Range("AD2:AD" & NumR).FormulaR1C1 = "=Test.xls!DictV(RC[-16])"` This particular function worked, because it had only one parameter (I used `Public DictN as Object`, which is why it didn't need `Dictionary` as parameter). Fundamental difference between these two functions is that now I use `Dictionary` as a parameter and formula doesnt identify **DictN** as a variable for **DictV**.

Comment: You want to make the DictN object available in one particular line of code. That is possible only by either declaring it as Public or generating it on the fly by means of a function. If you do neither you shouldn't complain about having no access to it.

Comment: @Zac is right in pointing out that you could avoid the dictionary by accessing the foreign workbook directly. That might be slow, however. But you are reading the source into an array and the array into the dictionary using the cell address as Key. Why don't you just use the array instead of the dictionary?

Comment: @ Variatus Because looping through an array to find a match or to use **`VLOOKUP`** to check other `Workbook` is slower than using a `Dictionary`. Alright, at this point I'm lost, no jokes, can you explain, why can't I use **DictN**? It isn't public, but I declared it in the same procedure and filled it.